# App Crashing after updating from 10.9.3 to 10.9.1

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I have mac version 10.9.3 and I am using xcode 5.1 on which I set build target 10.9. Now when I am running its build no 10.9.3 or latter versions it is good. But on previous versions it is not running.

Comment: Please update with crash log and relevant code which is causing the crash(if you have identified).

Answer (score 0):

It has solved, basically it was the problem with code signing. When I changed the code signing with Mac developer, the issue has resolved.